# Server deinitializes dvb card

Tags: debian-lenny

I have a problem with my home server. It deinitializes my dvb card after an unspecific time. Everything was fine, but i don't know what changed.

My kernelversion is  2.6.32-bpo.5-openvz-686 on a debian-lenny system.

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep dvb`

```
[ 6144.448014] dvb-usb: bulk message failed: -19 (8/0) 
[ 6144.448139] dvb-usb: bulk message failed: -19 (9/0) 
[ 6155.967995] dvb-usb: Opera1 DVB-S USB2.0 successfully deinitialized and disconnected.
```